# moving a control inside an application

Tags: windows, autohotkey, user-interface

I wanted to know if there is any tool that can allow me to move UI elements inside an application using script?

The details:
My father has glaucoma and his field of sight is very limited towards its lower side.
He is using the application version of whatsApp and would be happy if he could somehow move the message typing input box towards the top of the messages window.

I will also try to write to Meta (Facebook) and ask them to add such a setting for the benefit of people with this type of limitation.

but for now I was hoping that something like this can be done using maybe some tool like autohotkeys or something similar...

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not for just any application (or really most/all of them).

Applications control how they are drawn on the screen, so unless the application (or its runtime) has a feature specifically designed to let you modify the UI layout, you will not be able change anything, unless you have the application's code and the ability to modify and compile it.